# treats a chef's coat like a low-slung guitar

Tags: phrase-meaning

> On the appointed night, an hour or so before his reading, a crowd
>   starts to gather at a community center on O.C. Haley Boulevard, once a
>   Central City no-go zone between the Magnolia projects, birthplace of
>   the Cash Money record label, and the Calliope projects, where No Limit
>   rapper and founder Master P grew up. The city tore down both, and now
>   the neighborhood is a few months, maybe a year, from being acceptable
>   to suburban white people. There is still violence. This summer, a hit
>   man walked up to the St. John the Baptist Church and shot someone once
>   in the chest; meanwhile, half a mile away, chef Adolfo Garcia, a
>   culinary star in a city **that treats a chef's coat like a low-slung
>   guitar**, just opened his latest place.

([Beyond the Breach 08/24/15 • ESPN the Magazine](http://espn.go.com/espn/feature/story/_/id/13479768/wright-thompson-life-loss-renewal-new-orleans-10-years-hurricane-katrina))

It seems that "a low-slung guitar" to be  something looked upon. Am I right? If so, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A low slung guitar means one that's being worn while standing, with a long strap so that it hangs low on the body.  It's the normal way to hold an electric guitar while playing rock music.

[image: Slash]

This distinguishes it from folk or classical guitar, which is normally played sitting and held much higher up.

[image: John Williams]

So someone who is wearing a low slung guitar is presumably a rock star, i.e. someone who is a celebrity, considered to be cool and probably idolised by millions.

When it says that the city 'treats a chef's coat like a low-slung guitar' it means that the city treats someone who wears a chef's coat like someone who wears a low slung guitar.  Or more simply, it treats chefs like they're rock stars.

Comment: Nicely explained! +1

Answer (score -2):

You are correct, the passage is saying he cares for his coat.
I wouldn't say "to be looked up upon", just respected as they are "stylish".